# White box in "About me" on Android app

Tags: bug, profile-page, android-app

App version: 1.0.27
Devices affected: Nexus 7 and Toshiba Excite 10.1
Device not affected: Huawei Ascend G510

On a user's profile (e.g. [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/254778/howli) one), if there isn't much text in the "About me" section, then there is a white box on the right hand side of the screen.

[image: white box after "I like code"]

Comment: Erm.. not repro'd on v1.0.84 beta since the background is already white now, not light cyan.